# downgrading bootstrap from 4.3.1 to 3.3.7 with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have angular 6 project with bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap for modal dialog. Now, since this need to be integertaed to another project which is in angular 3.3.7 so, I was asked to downgrade the bootstrap version. Following are the steps I did:

```
    npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save
```

but after then my ng-bootstrap modal dialog stopped working so, when I try to re-install using below command:

```
     npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

then from ng_modules/bootstrap folder disappears then project shows nothing.
What am i missing?

Comment: There were a lot of breaking changes between Bootstrap 3 an 4.  I would not expect a library that outputs Bootstrap 4 markup to be compatible with Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

The same is working for me.
You can try changing Bootstrap version directly in package.json and remove node modules, then do npm i and run your application again.

You will need to write the code again for some part in Bootstrap 3 as there is no direct method available to go from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 3. There are probably too many assumptions because Bootstrap 4 handles things more with SASS, while Bootstrap 3 deals with LESS...so going from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 3 you are more likely to lose some styling that you may not be able to determine what’s missing.
Bootstrap 3 had used Normalize.css in order to render all the HTML elements their consistent appearance. Bootstrap 4 adopted an enhanced version of Normalize.css.
There are huge differences among both.
So you will have to check for each and every class very carefully while making this downgrade.
And that might be the reason your modal stopped working.